# Network adapters not working

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, broadcom

After restarting my pc today I saw the Ethernet symbol in the task bar with the wireless symbol gone . After checking I found that the wlan driver was not there under the network adapter in device manager. I was also unable to update the driver downloaded from the Dell website due to the error of unsupported hardware because I could not switch on my wifi switch since the wlan driver was missing. So I tried restarting and then as if by magic I got the network drivers listed under the network adapters in device manager. It is still not able to search for the available networks. Sometimes after restarting it automatically connects itself but after a while shows no Internet access and when I try to reconnect, it again goes back to wireless symbol with a red cross on the task bar.

1. I have tried updating the drivers from the dell website same issue..
2. When i try to disable the wlan driver from network connections and enable it  my pc freezes and restarts aftr some time.
3. Have tried resetting the bios to factory defaults.
4. Windows networking diagnostics tells me to turn on the wireless switch. But It does not switch on. Have checked the services menu all the important services like WLAN auto configuration are set to automatic.

I am using a dell latitude e6420 atg pc with dw 1501 wlan half mini card and Intel (r) 82579LM gigabit network connection. 
I also have a dual booted system with ubuntu 15.10 installed as the other os. I cannot access the wireless networks from either os. 
Any help is appreciated..?!